# JSONDecodeError OutputParserException: Could not parse function call data: Unterminated string starting at: line 99 column 21 (char 4514)

Tags: python, json, error-handling, langchain

I have a problem with code of langchain on google colab:

```
# @title
!pip -q install openai langchain tiktoken pinecone-client python-dotenv

# Make the display a bit wider
# from IPython.display import display, HTML
# display(HTML("<style>.container { width:90% !important; }</style>"))

# LangChain basics
from langchain.chat_models import ChatOpenAI
from langchain.text_splitter import RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter
from langchain.chains.summarize import load_summarize_chain
from langchain.chains import create_extraction_chain

# Vector Store and retrievals
from langchain.embeddings.openai import OpenAIEmbeddings
from langchain.chains import RetrievalQA
from langchain.vectorstores import Pinecone
import pinecone

# Chat Prompt templates for dynamic values
from langchain.prompts.chat import (
    ChatPromptTemplate,
    SystemMessagePromptTemplate,
    HumanMessagePromptTemplate
)

# Supporting libraries
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()

# Creating two versions of the model so I can swap between gpt3.5 and gpt4
llm3 = ChatOpenAI(temperature=0,
                  openai_api_key=os.getenv('OPENAI_API_KEY', '-----'),
                  model_name="gpt-3.5-turbo-0613",
                  request_timeout = 180
                )

llm4 = ChatOpenAI(temperature=0,
                  openai_api_key=os.getenv('OPENAI_API_KEY', '-----'),
                  model_name="gpt-4-0613",
                  request_timeout = 180
                 )

from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/gdrive')

with open('/content/gdrive/MyDrive/Nauka/rozmowa_timestamp.txt', 'r') as file:
    transcript = file.read()

print ("Transkrypcja:\n")
print(content[:215])


text_splitter = RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter(separators=["\n\n", "\n",], chunk_size=4000, chunk_overlap=800)

docs = text_splitter.create_documents([transcript[:transcript_subsection_characters]])
print (f"You have {len(docs)} docs. First doc is {llm3.get_num_tokens(docs[0].page_content)} tokens")

template="""
You are a helpful assistant that helps retrieve topics talked about in a podcast transcript
- Your goal is to extract the topic names and brief 1-sentence description of the topic
- Topics include:
  - Themes
  - Business Ideas
  - Interesting Stories
  - Money making businesses
  - Quick stories about people
  - Mental Frameworks
  - Stories about an industry
  - Analogies mentioned
  - Advice or words of caution
  - Pieces of news or current events
- Provide a brief description of the topics after the topic name. Example: 'Topic: Brief Description'
- Use the same words and terminology that is said in the podcast
- Do not respond with anything outside of the podcast. If you don't see any topics, say, 'No Topics'
- Do not respond with numbers, just bullet points
- Do not include anything about 'Marketing Against the Grain'
- Only pull topics from the transcript. Do not use the examples
- Make your titles descriptive but concise. Example: 'Shaan's Experience at Twitch' should be 'Shaan's Interesting Projects At Twitch'
- A topic should be substantial, more than just a one-off comment

% START OF EXAMPLES
 - List of the participants in the meeting: The meeting was attended by 3 people and they were Mr. Adam Nowak, Michał Kowalski and Mrs. Janina Jóźwiak.
 - Determining the method of supporting the panel: The panels will be supported continuously on the vertical substructure. Expansion of materials will be compensated by openings for bean-shaped connectors.
 - Installation method: The window will be mounted in the wall on Halfen system brackets. A so-called warm assembly will be used.
 - Customer Guidance: Due to Kingspan's corporate guidelines, only European Technical Approval (ETA) fasteners should be used.
 - Task to be performed: Mr. Marcin Nowak will prepare a set of data necessary to perform the calculations and send it to the static engineer by the end of next week (26:08:2023).
 - Wind load: The customer expects that the wind load for the second wind zone, i.e. 1.4kPa, will be used for calculations.
 - Date of completion of the task: The completion date of the building is planned for 12/12/2013. At present, the construction manager does not anticipate any deviations from the schedule.
% END OF EXAMPLES
"""
system_message_prompt_map = SystemMessagePromptTemplate.from_template(template)

human_template="Transcript: {text}" # Simply just pass the text as a human message
human_message_prompt_map = HumanMessagePromptTemplate.from_template(human_template)

chat_prompt_map = ChatPromptTemplate.from_messages(messages=[system_message_prompt_map, human_message_prompt_map])

template="""
You are a helpful assistant that helps retrieve topics talked about in a engineer call transcript
- you answer only in Polish
- You will be given a series of bullet topics of topics vound
- Your goal is to exract the topic names and brief 1-sentence description of the topic
- Deduplicate any bullet points you see
- Only pull topics from the transcript. Do not use the examples

% START OF EXAMPLES
 - Type of building: The building has a fire resistance class of ZL3. The height of the building is 12 meters. Emergency exits have roofs.
 - Properties of the paint coating: The paint coating of the product is made of Dupont powder paint. The coating thickness is 125 microns. The coating applied to the product is Qualicoat certified and approved for outdoor use.
% END OF EXAMPLES
"""
system_message_prompt_map = SystemMessagePromptTemplate.from_template(template)

human_template="Transcript: {text}" # Simply just pass the text as a human message
human_message_prompt_map = HumanMessagePromptTemplate.from_template(human_template)

chat_prompt_combine = ChatPromptTemplate.from_messages(messages=[system_message_prompt_map, human_message_prompt_map])

chain = load_summarize_chain(llm3,
                             chain_type="map_reduce",
                             map_prompt=chat_prompt_map,
                             combine_prompt=chat_prompt_combine,
#                              verbose=True
                            )

topics_found = chain.run({"input_documents": docs})

print (topics_found)

schema = {
    "properties": {
        # The title of the topic
        "topic_name": {
            "type": "string",
            "description" : "The title of the topic listed"
        },
        # The description
        "description": {
            "type": "string",
            "description" : "The description of the topic listed"
        },
        "tag": {
            "type": "string",
            "description" : "The type of content being described",
            "enum" : ['Technical details', 'Task', 'Assumptions', 'Formal details', 'Important dates']
        }
    },
    "required": ["topic_name", "description"],
}

# Using gpt3.5 here because this is an easy extraction task and no need to jump to gpt4
chain = create_extraction_chain(schema, llm3)

topics_structured = chain.run(topics_found)

topics_structured
```

Douring execution line topics_execution = chain.run(topics, found) I get an error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
JSONDecodeError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/langchain/output_parsers/openai_functions.py in parse_result(self, result)
     51             try:
---> 52                 return json.loads(function_call_info, strict=self.strict)
     53             except (json.JSONDecodeError, TypeError) as exc:

11 frames
/usr/lib/python3.10/json/__init__.py in loads(s, cls, object_hook, parse_float, parse_int, parse_constant, object_pairs_hook, **kw)
    358         kw['parse_constant'] = parse_constant
--> 359     return cls(**kw).decode(s)

/usr/lib/python3.10/json/decoder.py in decode(self, s, _w)
    336         """
--> 337         obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
    338         end = _w(s, end).end()

/usr/lib/python3.10/json/decoder.py in raw_decode(self, s, idx)
    352         try:
--> 353             obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
    354         except StopIteration as err:

JSONDecodeError: Unterminated string starting at: line 99 column 21 (char 4514)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

OutputParserException                     Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-91-a695b4dd4b90> in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 topics_structured = chain.run(topics_found)

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/langchain/chains/base.py in run(self, callbacks, tags, metadata, *args, **kwargs)
    473             if len(args) != 1:
    474                 raise ValueError("`run` supports only one positional argument.")
--> 475             return self(args[0], callbacks=callbacks, tags=tags, metadata=metadata)[
    476                 _output_key
    477             ]

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/langchain/chains/base.py in __call__(self, inputs, return_only_outputs, callbacks, tags, metadata, include_run_info)
    280         except (KeyboardInterrupt, Exception) as e:
    281             run_manager.on_chain_error(e)
--> 282             raise e
    283         run_manager.on_chain_end(outputs)
    284         final_outputs: Dict[str, Any] = self.prep_outputs(

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/langchain/chains/base.py in __call__(self, inputs, return_only_outputs, callbacks, tags, metadata, include_run_info)
    274         try:
    275             outputs = (
--> 276                 self._call(inputs, run_manager=run_manager)
    277                 if new_arg_supported
    278                 else self._call(inputs)

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/langchain/chains/llm.py in _call(self, inputs, run_manager)
     90     ) -> Dict[str, str]:
     91         response = self.generate([inputs], run_manager=run_manager)
---> 92         return self.create_outputs(response)[0]
     93 
     94     def generate(

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/langchain/chains/llm.py in create_outputs(self, llm_result)
    218     def create_outputs(self, llm_result: LLMResult) -> List[Dict[str, Any]]:
    219         """Create outputs from response."""
--> 220         result = [
    221             # Get the text of the top generated string.
    222             {

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/langchain/chains/llm.py in <listcomp>(.0)
    221             # Get the text of the top generated string.
    222             {
--> 223                 self.output_key: self.output_parser.parse_result(generation),
    224                 "full_generation": generation,
    225             }

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/langchain/output_parsers/openai_functions.py in parse_result(self, result)
     74 
     75     def parse_result(self, result: List[Generation]) -> Any:
---> 76         res = super().parse_result(result)
     77         return res[self.key_name]
     78 

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/langchain/output_parsers/openai_functions.py in parse_result(self, result)
     52                 return json.loads(function_call_info, strict=self.strict)
     53             except (json.JSONDecodeError, TypeError) as exc:
---> 54                 raise OutputParserException(
     55                     f"Could not parse function call data: {exc}"
     56                 )

OutputParserException: Could not parse function call data: Unterminated string starting at: line 99 column 21 (char 4514)
```

I were expecting that it will work. I am trying to complete this tutorial on my own data: https://youtu.be/pEkxRQFNAs4?si=kRa3siFD8GYfZ3Zo

Code of the tutorial:
https://github.com/gkamradt/langchain-tutorials/blob/main/data_generation/Topic%20Modeling%20With%20Language%20Models.ipynb

But i get an error :(

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to say it: i just janged the code in the part where is limitation of signs and its working :)

In this case text splitter should look like this:

```
# Load up your text splitter
text_splitter = RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter(separators=["\n\n", "\n",], chunk_size=4000, chunk_overlap=800)

docs = text_splitter.create_documents([transcript])
print (f"You have {len(docs)} docs. First doc is {llm3.get_num_tokens(docs[0].page_content)} tokens")
```

But how and why it works... not me You should ask :P
As soon as i get the sollution I inform You dear World. I know You have just stopped, and was all nervous waiting for the sollution for my problem... but don't bather yourself, You can proceed :)